# Angular error help: Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):

Tags: angular

Your help is very much important for me.

I was working on Angular[image] code to Populate colors on the dropdown menu.

But I am getting an error here, I have been trying to fix it, however I couldn't resolve the issue.

Any help is much appreciated. I am attaching the screenshot of the error.

Error Description:
"./src/styles.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDQUR.jpg).rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDQUR.jpg)!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDQUR.jpg).rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./src/styles.css - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css'

Comment: Have you run `npm install` in the project directory?

Comment: I think  the path is incorrect in **angular.json** or **package.json** file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your response.
The issue was resolved when following change was made to style.css.
It was fixed when ../ was replaced with ~/ in the below path
@import url('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')